# gap properties are not working on older safari browsers, I need to polyfill gap propeties. Im using tailwind with Nextjs

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

My current postcss.config.js looks like this:
How to fix this gap property issue.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009',
      },
      stage: 3,
      features: {
        'custom-properties': false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Could you solve this? I'm facing the same issue